# python variables as index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with different sheets and column-heading but same structure. I want to convert to json. but already now I have a problem. How can I index, my first column(with different heading) to pandas?

```
import pandas;
datapath = 'myfile.xlsx'
datasheet = 'testsheet'

data = pandas.read_excel(datapath, sheet_name=datasheet)
index_1 = data.columns[0]

# now my problem, in bash I would do it like:
chipset = data.$(echo $index_1)
print(chipset)
# can anyone give me please a solution?
```

I have a excel-file (sx) sheet:

```
s1:
s1 col1:  | s1col2
sc11data1 | sc12data1
sc11data2 | sc12data2
---
s2:
s2 col1: | s2col2
sc21data | sc22data
--
```

I dont know how the exact name of the heading in a sheet is but 1st sheet is always a index in my json.

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to understand your question. Do you mean you want to set the first column as the index? Doesn't   `data.set_index(index_1,inplace=True)` work?